# Base for topology with group structure

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a group for $a \in G$ let $U_{a}:=\left\{g a g^{-1} \mid g \in G\right\}$ ,

i) show  that $\{ U_a \}_{a\in G}$ is a
base for  some topology on $G$.

ii) this topology is Hausdorff iff $G$ is an abelian group .

iii) when this topology is metrizable ?

For  i The first property of base is essentially trivial. We need to show that any $a \in G$ belongs to at least one of those sets ( note that because $ a \in U_a $ ). Now for any $a \neq b$
we have $\mathrm{U}_{\text {a }} \cap \mathrm{U}_{\mathrm{b}}=\varnothing$ then this is a base for some topology on $G$ .for ii if $G$ be abelian group then for any $a \in G$ we have $U_a = \{a\}$ and any $U_a = \{a\}$ is open then this topology is hausdorff . For iii I think $G$ is metrizable iff $G$ be Abelian and meter is discrete metric because any single point set is open .

Comment: Why is $a \in U_a$?

Comment: It's not necessarily true that $a\neq b$ implies $U_a\cap U_b = \emptyset$.  But it is true that that for any $a,b$, either $U_a = U_b$ or $U_a\cap U_b = \emptyset$.

Comment: For (iii) it might help you to think of a more general question: if $U_\alpha$ is a collection of pairwise disjoint subsets of a set $X$ such that $X = \bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha$, when is the topology on $X$ that has the $U_\alpha$ as a base metrizable? (This leads to the answer you give in the special case when the $U_\alpha$ are the conjugacy classes of a group $G$.)

Comment: @azif00 . because $1 \in G $ .

Comment: @azif00 $a = aaa^{-1}$.

Comment: You've shown that this topology is metrizable when $G$ is abelian. What about the converse?